# Resque background process: uninitialized constant SampleController::Resque Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduled-tasks, background-process, resque

I am getting the following while executing the job asynchronously by using Resque scheduler.

```
uninitialized constant SampleController::Resque
```

I have the folloiwng code in `sample_controller.rb`:

```
Resque.enqueue(RailsWorker,{:model=>object.class.to_s,:object_id=>object.id,:meth=>:sync_object})
```

I have already started Resque by using `resque:work` rake task.

Can anyone help me to fix this error?